# Yii2 form does not work — Class 'yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm' not found

Tags: yii2

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;


$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']);

ActiveForm::end(); 
?>
```

If i run this code the following **error** will occur.

> **Fatal error**: Class 'yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm' not found in
>   E:\wamp\www\yii2-paypal-master\backend\views\site\login.php on line 6

Kindly help me to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
```

with

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
```

Form:

```
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'],
    ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->errorSummary($model) ?>

 <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

  <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: If i use above code means the following error will occur 

    (Class 'yii\widgets\ActiveForm' not found)

Comment: have you created project using `composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application` ?

Comment: @muhammad Shahzad 

N i can download from **github**

Comment: @Gautham.M if you download the yii2-app-advanced template directly from github you will miss the vendor directory with all the packages, i.e. all the classes you are missing.

Comment: pls confirm, is there vendor directory in your project root directory.

Comment: @Muhammad Shahzad No there is no vendor directory

Comment: That's the issue, run command in your cmd: `composer install`,

Comment: The following error will occur  **Could not open input file: init**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111127/discussion-between-gautham-m-and-muhammad-shahzad).

Answer (score 1):

First, check the file `assets/AppAsset.php` if your Class App Asset is like mine, using Boostrap 3 or 4 or o:

```
public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

You need to change it to use `yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm`; change this to instead use `yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm;` it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks very much